# Realizable subsets of the sphere at infinity

Tags: geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose we have an arbitrary finite collection $X = (x_i)_{i = 1} ^ n$ of the boundary sphere $\partial D$ where $D$ represents the Poincare disk. Does there exist a (discrete?) subgroup $G$ of the isometry group of $D$ whose limiting set $\Lambda(G)$ is $X$? I know $G$ is not elementary as long as $n > 2$.

I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ consists of the $n$th degree roots of unity.

Comment: Nope. Pretty much any textbook on Kleinian groups will prove that the limit set of a nonelementary subgroup will have cardinality of continuum.

Comment: Don't Kleinian groups specifically refer to actions on $\mathbb{H}^3$? What if D is the two dimensional Poincare disk?

Comment: Not necessarily. Dimension does not matter. If you understand proof in a particular dimension you will see that it works in all dimensions.